# How to count edges for a single node?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a dataset with two columns each represents a participant (name, surname) of accident. So I made a graph from this data, and now I need to count the number of edges for each participant i.e. how many times a person was in accident with others.

I use `networkx` lib for this, it has `.number_of_edges()` method but it counts 1 for every participant.

```
df = pd.read_excel('выборка.xlsx', index_col='№ страхового события')
df.columns = ['part_1', 'part_2']
G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'part_1', 'part_2')

for i in G:
    for j in G:
        if G.number_of_edges(j, i) > 0:
            print(G.number_of_edges(j, i))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without your construction code for G its not possible to say whats wrong.

Comment: Maybe it is simply correct. Here you are counting the number of times a participant is in an accident with a specific other one. Are pairs of people supposed to be implicated together into several accidents ? I don't know the type of accident, but in real-life car accidents it is unlikely.

Comment: @voiDnyx I've added the construction code.

Comment: @JulienD Some people have have more than 1 accidents, but with another one. And yes, it's a car accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not doing what you think it does. You are counting the number of times a participant (i) is in an accident with a specific other one (j), which is likely to be 1.

If you want for each participant, the number of times it has an accident with *any* other participant, you can use for instance

```
for i in G:
    print(len(G.edges(i)))
```

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.edges.html#edges